# How to troubleshoot .app bundle not working

Tags: jar, .app

I have been making an application using Javafx, and have finished the project turning it into an application. However, when I try to run the application it immediatley crashes with know error messages, nothing is printed to the console. As a note, the .jar file runs if clicked. This has led me to believe that the problem is with my file structure namely the fact that their are 2 binary files in the Java folder.

Here is my .app packages contents:
[image]

A fix to my problem would be nice, however beyond that how should one go about debugging this sort of thing, I can not find any log messages, can it be done?

Edit: Nothing is printed when in terminal I use `open -a ApplicationName` and the application crashes. And here is my info.plist. 
[image]

Comment: Try launching from the command line and capture any errors printed to the console.

Comment: nothing is printed to the command line when the app is opened, through the console. Nothing is printed to the mac Console either.

Comment: What command are you using to launch? What do you see in the console when the app quits? Please [edit] your question to include both of these details.

Comment: @MattClark I edited it, although there is not much to say

Comment: @MattClark such a method of running it so that their are log messages is what I am looking for.